# Detect specific image is loaded then do something...

Tags: jquery, css

I'm getting my head around JS/Jquery slowly and I need help/guidance on how to detect when a "specific" image is "visible", so I can then remove a class on a different element. Simple I'm sure...just trying to understand the logic.

**JS.**.

```
$('.my-big-hero').find('my-image-here.jpg:visible').removeClass('class-i-want-removed');
```

This is probably a simple *(and wrong way)* to display this, but it was to give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. I've tried various ways to write this and not winning.

Appreciate any help you can give....thank you in advanced.

Comment: `if($('.my-big-hero').find('my-image-here.jpg').is(":visible")){
 $(this).removeClass('class-i-want-removed');
}`

Comment: Here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613844/how-to-check-image-is-visible-or-not

Comment: I like this question - you're likely to get a few answers that all do the same thing. I'll give my own shortly :-)

Comment: ...everyone who has replied so far...thank you!!! I'm going through the different solutions now to see which one best suits my logic. Brilliant...thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.is("visible")` and the `toggleClass` functions, this way:

```
$('.my-big-hero').find('my-image-here.jpg').toggleClass('class-i-want-removed', !$(this).is(':visible'));
```

Then the element will have the class `class-i-want-removed` if it is not visible, and the class will be removed once it is visible.

Comment: ..thank you @amhev. It's not quite working the way I want to but just seeing your logic is helping me understand jquery a little more....will keep trying to see if I can use your logic and the others I get a response from :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, you might be able to do something like this?:

```
$(".my-big-hero").find("my.image.here.jpg").on("load", function() {
   $(this).removeClass("class-i-want-removed");
});
```